# Open GL single line in an image is rendered

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to playback video using Open GL-ES. I was able to create the window, surface, shaders, program and set Vertex attributes. But the image is not getting displayed properly. Only a single vertical line in the image is rendered in the entire frame. I'm new to OpenGL and not being able to figure out the issue. I've attached the expected image and the current rendered image . Pixels in the bottom right corner of the original image are  only being rendered. Can anyone please help me?

[Current rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvLlB.jpg)

[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URYmh.jpg)

Comment: Is there any code or something you can show so ppl can have a point to start helping you with ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue -

I had set incorrect the texture scale location

Correct one :

```
 glUniform2f(gl_tex_scale_loc[0],
             1, 1);

 glUniform2f (gl_tex_scale_loc[1],
             0, 1);

 glUniform2f (gl_tex_scale_loc[2],
             0, 1);
```

Previously:

```
 glUniform2f(gl_tex_scale_loc[0],
             1, 1);
 glUniform2f (gl_tex_scale_loc[1],
             1, 1);
 glUniform2f (gl_tex_scale_loc[2],
             1, 1);
```

I'm not very sure of how this translates to the above behaviour. But it solved my problem